# Is an isolated subset of $\Bbb R$` always nowhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis

By "isolated set" I mean a set composed only of isolated points. I considered the set of the reciprocals of the positive integers, the closure of which includes $0$. That closure has an empty interior. But is there some other set where the implication fails?

I have continued to work. Perhaps this is right. Assume that $A$ is isolated and that $A$  fails to be nowhere dense. Then there exists some $x$ in the interior of the closure of $A$. So every open ball around $x$ is a subset of the closure. Let $y$ be a point in an arbitrary open ball. Then $y$ is either a point of $A$ or a limit point of $A$. If $y$ is a limit point of $A$, there is a point of $A$ in the intersection of the ball around $x$ and the ball around $y$. So there is in every ball around $x$ another point of $a$ not equal to $x$. Thus $x$ is not isolated, a contradiction.

Comment: I think I found a proof by contradiction. Call the set A. If the interior of the closure of A is no empty, tHen there exist x in A with an open ball in A, implying that other points of A are arbitrarily close and therefore that x is not isolated. Does this sound correct?

Comment: There is a useful equivalent formulation of "$A$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb R$": For each point $x \in A$ and for each nonempty open interval $I$ such that $x \in I,$ there exists a nonempty open subinterval $J$ of $I$ such that $J \cap A = \emptyset.$ Using this formulation (which is good to know anyway because it's often useful in proving sets are nowhere dense), the result is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it more directly by using the property that the closure of a set is the union of the set and its limit points.

For your isolated set $A$, determine what the limit points must be. Once you have that, it should not be too difficult to show the interior of the closure is empty.

Comment: Does an isolated set have something special about its limit points? I am used to the reciprocals of the naturals and their limit point 0.

Comment: @senseless apprentice: The closure of an isolated set can be "large". For example, given any Cantor set in $\mathbb R$ (that is, a bounded perfect nowhere dense set; actually, "bounded" can be omitted for this), the set of midpoints of the bounded open complementary intervals form an isolated set whose closure is the original Cantor set union the set of midpoints. Thus, the closure of an isolated set can have positive Lebesgue measure, among other things. Note: Instead of "midpoints", any choice of a not-necessarily-uniformly-chosen point in each of the open complementary intervals would work.

Comment: As a follow-up comment, I suspect that every closed nowhere dense set is the closure of some isolated set. This sounds like something I should know, but off-hand I don't know if this is true.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working with subsets $A$ of the real line $R$ (otherwise, there are counterexamples). Suppose that the closure of $A$ contains an open nonempty interval $I$ in $R$. Then for every open nonempty subinterval $J\subset I$ the intersection $A\cap J$ is infinite. Pick a point $a\in I$. Then every open interval $(a-\epsilon, a+ \epsilon)\subset I$ contains a point of $A$ different from $a$. Therefore, $a$ is not an isolated point of $A$. qed

Comment: Thanks. I am not used to working with intervals other nbhds in this context. Yes, I am working with the line, which I should have mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by "intervals other nbhds"?

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to typing on this device. I am used to considering open balls around points. I understand a nbhd of x is any set containing an open ball around x, but in my class we are pretty much treating nbhd in the more specific sense of open ball. It's topology for an intro to analysis class. Since I am studying for a test, I am trying to work within the tools officially given to us by our book by Thomson.Bruckner.Bruckner.

Comment: Every open interval is also an open ball centered at its middle point.